# How do I force-delete a file on my computer?

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, delete-file

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan Public Beta 2.

There is somehow a permission problem with my Desktop (and only this directory) because I can not delete any file.

The classic delete to bin does not work, even though I am prompted a window asking for my password and permission. (I am the administrator).

I also tried a few command lines like `sudo rm - R *file*` and it tells me that the operation is not permitted even after I enter my password.

Going without the rootless feature of El Capitan did not help either :

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0" 
sudo reboot
```

Should I change the permissions of the Desktop directory? If so what are the original ones?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After numerous try the answer was dead-easy : there is a "lock" option on files and directories in OS X and it was active for my desktop (right click -> information). Interesting is the fact that no command line could break it.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the "rootless" feature introduced in El Capitan... You can find more information about it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) .

To disable "rootless", type this in the terminal (you'll have to reboot for the change to apply):

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks! if something goes wrong/it does not work, how do I go back to before these commands? Is there any risk executing them? (I mean is it bad for security?) thanks again

Comment: `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=1"` and reboot to re-enable the feature. Remember that this disables a security feature, but it is known to get in your way sometimes. Considering running without rootless is not very different from the situation on OS X before, I'd say it's not that bad.